# Font Size is not saving in DB - ckeditor

Tags: php, codeigniter, ckeditor

I am using Full package of ckeditor and here i am facing a strange problem from 2 days. Everything is working fine but `font-size` is not working at all . when I select a line and change it's font size, it shows the correct code in source mode:

```
<span style="font-size:9px">My selected line</span>
```

but when i save this result in database it converts this line to something like below.

```
<span xss=removed> My selected line</span>
```

I am using CodeIgniter and not using any special function before saving my data. just using `post` function of CI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like codeigniter cleans your html against XSS attacks.

Use it with caution:

> $this->input->post('html', false);

The second parameter will disable the XSS filter.

Comment: Yeah I will.. waiting for 10 mins to complete :) as per SO policy :/

Comment: but, is this secure? when we want prinft the code in a view

Comment: @metalbox No, is not but sometimes is necessary. That's why I said "Use it with caution".

Comment: right, in any case i use strip_tags and preg_replace to try avoid some tags like <script>, php, onmouseover ....., maybe i am crazy lol

Answer (score 1):

```
  $this->input->post($ck_editor_contents, false);
```

This one disable the post filtering and save all to the DB.

Answer (score 0):

$this->input->post($ck_editor_contents, false);
and remove below link when data insert and update case
$posted_data = $this->security->xss_clean($posted_data)

you can also use other method editor content
`$where = "products_id = '".$res['products_id']."'";
$posted_data2 = array('products_description'=>$this->input-post('products_description',false));
$this->product_model->safe_update('wl_products',$posted_data2,$where,FALSE);`
[Source](http://%20https://www.findinall.com/blog/font-awesome-not%E2%80%A6owing-as-squares/)